# Golf Scores Array - Actionscript 3.0

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I am making a program which has the user enter a golf score which then stores it in an array. However, the user can only enter up to 18 scores and I have attempted to code a prompt which indicates the number of scores that are in the array/they have entered. The label is called lblPrompt1 and it does not function. I also want to disable the addscore button when the user has entered all 18 scores. The prompt does not function. Please advise. Thanks!

```
// Purpose: To add golf scores to an array

// This line makes the button, btnAddScore wait for a mouse click
// When the button is clicked, the addName function is called
btnAddScore.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addScore);

// This line makes the button, btnDisplayScores wait for a mouse click
// When the button is clicked, the displayScores function is called
btnDisplayScores.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, displayScores);

// declare the global variables
var scores: Array = new Array(); // array of golf scores

// This is the addName function
// e:MouseEvent is the click event experienced by the button
// void indicates that the function does not return a value
function addScore(e: MouseEvent): void {

    // declare the variables
    var golfScore: String; // friend's name entered by user
    // get the name from the user
    golfScore = txtinScore.text;
    // append the name to the end of the array
    scores.push(golfScore);
    // display the length of the array in the label
    lblArraySize.text = "Number of Golf Scores Entered: " + scores.length;

}
// This is the displayNames function
// e:MouseEvent is the click event experienced by the button
// void indicates that the function does not return a value
function displayScores(e: MouseEvent): void {
    var holeNumber: Number;
    lblScores.text = "";
    for (var x = 0; x < scores.length; x++) {

        lblScores.text += scores[x] + "\r";

    }

    holeNumber++;
    if (holeNumber <= 18) {

        lblPrompt1.text = "Enter the score for hole #" + holeNumber.toString() + ":";

    } else {

        lblPrompt1.text = "All scores are entered.";
        txtinScore.text = "";
        btnAddScore.enabled = false;

    }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you were more specific about what is and isn't working,  and what your problem statement is.

Comment: The **Number** class has a default value of **undefined** that's why **holeNumber++;** does not produce anything meaningful. Use the **int** class instead because a) it has a default value of 0 and b) you don't need it to be a floating point value anyway. Then, when you use the **Number** class, don't forget to give it an initial value, for example: **var a:Number = 0;**

Answer (score 3):

While it's not very clear what you are asking,  one issue you have is that your `holeNumber` variable will never have a numeric value - it will always be `NaN` (**N**ot **A** **N**umber).

Whenever the display scores button is clicked, inside the click handler function (`displayScores`), you create this variable (`holeNumber`) and you don't give it a value.  Numbers default to `NaN`,  so later when you increment it with `holeNumber++`, you'll just end up with `NaN` still (because `NaN` plus `1` is still `NaN`).

The other part of that issue, is you create the variable in the scope of the click handler, and only increment it once, so even if you changed the var definition to `var holeNumber:Number = 0;`, it would still have a value of `1` every time you clicked because every click the variable get's recreated and then incremented by 1.

What you probably want to do, is forgo the `holeNumber` var altogether and just reference `scores.length` as that is essentially the current hole.

```
function displayScores(e: MouseEvent): void {
    lblScores.text = "";
    for (var x = 0; x < scores.length; x++) {
        lblScores.text += scores[x] + "\r";
    }

    //use scores.length instead of holeNumber
    if (scores.length < 18) {

        lblPrompt1.text = "Enter the score for hole #" + String(scores.length + 1) + ":";
        //adding 1 to the length because that would be the next hole number

    } else {

        lblPrompt1.text = "All scores are entered.";
        txtinScore.text = "";
        btnAddScore.enabled = false;

    }
}
```